# kylix AnsiCompareStr bug?

Tags: linux, delphi, glibc, kylix

The following program tries to use AnsiCompareStr/Text:

```
program Project5;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses StrUtils, SysUtils;

begin
  Writeln('Ord(''-'')=', Ord('-'));
  Writeln('Ord(''_'')=', Ord('_'));
  Writeln('AnsiCompareStr(''-'', ''_'')=', AnsiCompareStr('-', '_'));
  Writeln('AnsiCompareText(''-'', ''_'')=', AnsiCompareText('-', '_'));
  Writeln('WideCompareStr(''-'', ''_'')=', WideCompareStr('-', '_'));
  Writeln('WideCompareText(''-'', ''_'')=', WideCompareText('-', '_'));
  Writeln('CompareStr(''-'', ''_'')=', CompareStr('-', '_'));
  Writeln('CompareText(''-'', ''_'')=', CompareText('-', '_'));
  Readln;
end.
```

When compiled with Kylix, it outputs wrong results on CentOS 5/6 x64:

```
Ord('-')=45
Ord('_')=95
AnsiCompareStr('-', '_')=3   <--- should be negative
AnsiCompareText('-', '_')=3  <--- should be negative
WideCompareStr('-', '_')=3   <--- should be negative
WideCompareText('-', '_')=3  <--- should be negative
CompareStr('-', '_')=-50
CompareText('-', '_')=-50
```

I wonder why AnsiCompareStr/Text gives wrong results ?

PS: CompareStr is considered obsolete according to http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=CompareStr . AnsiCompareStr is considered to be the modern, Locale safe form of CompareStr according to http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=AnsiCompareStr .

PS: The locale is en_US.iso885915 and/or en_US.UTF8

PS: Kylix 3 (as Delphi 7 with CrossKylix)

```
function AnsiCompareStr(const S1, S2: string): Integer;
begin
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Result := CompareString(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, PChar(S1), Length(S1),
    PChar(S2), Length(S2)) - 2;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF LINUX}
  // glibc 2.1.2 / 2.1.3 implementations of strcoll() and strxfrm()
  // have severe capacity limits.  Comparing two 100k strings may
  // exhaust the stack and kill the process.
  // Fixed in glibc 2.1.91 and later.
  Result := strcoll(PChar(S1), PChar(S2));
{$ENDIF}
end;

function AnsiCompareText(const S1, S2: string): Integer;
begin
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Result := CompareString(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORECASE, PChar(S1),
    Length(S1), PChar(S2), Length(S2)) - 2;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF LINUX}
  Result := WideCompareText(S1, S2);
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnsiCompareStr/Text` are giving correct results. They reflect the ordering defined by the prevailing locale. For instance `AnsiCompareStr` is implemented with a simple call to `strcoll` from the glibc standard library.

The problem is in your expectations. I'm not sure why you expect the results you do, but it's quite reasonable to expect that `glibc` implements collation correctly. The order implied by `strcoll` is the collation order for the prevailing locale, whatever that happens to be. You didn't state that in the question.

Perhaps the clue is that you use the phrase *locale safe*. Well, `CompareXXX` are independent of locale, `AnsiCompareXXX` depend upon the locale. If you are looking for locale invariant ordering then `AnsiCompareXXX` are the wrong choice.

Comment: Sorry but your explanation is hardly convincing.

Comment: Then submit a bug report to the glibc developers telling them that `strcoll` is defective. It's difficult for me to say more. You didn't say why you expected negative values.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions !

Comment: I still don't know the locale and hence collation. But `strcoll` will be accurate. You just have to gain understanding of why `strcoll` behaves as it does. Do you appreciate that you should expect different results on different locales?

Comment: @DavidHefferman  I understand much better by reading http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/ and http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/locale/ . Thank you for your suggestions !